# Import Class to main script from subdirectory

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a directory structure like this

```
main.py
markdown-extensions/
    __init__.py
    doc_extension.py
```

Here is my doc_extension.py (it's intended to be a bare bones markdown post processor):

```
from markdown.postprocessors import Postprocessor
class DocsPostProcessor(Postprocessor):
    def run(self, text):
        return "<h1>hello world</h1>"

class DocsExtension:
    def extendMarkdown(self,md):
        postProcessor = DocsPostProcessor()
        postProcessor.md = md
        md.postprocessors.add(postProcessor)
```

How do I go about importing it into my main.py? I've tried variations on the following to no avail:

```
import markdown-extensions.doc_extension
import markdown-extensions.*
import markdown-extensions.doc_extension
```

Comment: You cannot have `-` in a module name (or in any other name).

Comment: thanks, if you add that as the answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` sign is not a valid character for a Python name (also known as *identifier*), whether it is a module or not. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

from markdown-extensions.doc_extension import *

but rather be explicit, as * will import all global variables, methods and classes.  So:

from markdown-extensions.doc_extension import DocsPostProcessor, DocsExtension

*edit
And yes besides that you can't have "-"s, I mistook it for a "_".